# Linear Alg. Short proof on determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Hi can I get a quick check on my proof to see if it is correct.

[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unedr.png)

[image]

Comment: You seem to be reducing the proposition you want to prove about systems of equations being solvable to a proposition about matrix inverses existing iff the determinant is nonzero.  If the latter is established, you would be better off showing that the systems of equations are solvable iff the matrix is invertible, and then using the known proposition that this happens iff the determinant is nonzero.  To make a specific comment, I don't see the logic of the sentence beginning "It follows that $ad-bc$," or how you could write an expression for $A^{-1}$ which involves dividing by zero.

Comment: How should I  go about this starting from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

We are assumed to know that the inverse of a matrix $A$ exists iff $\det A\ne 0$ (assumed knowledge which I infer from StillLearning's proposed solution). We look at the simultaneous equations $ax+by=e$, $cx+dy=f$, and want to know when they have a solution $x, y$ for every $e$ and $f$.  We show that this happens iff the matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$
is invertible.  Based on our assumption, that proves that the equations are solvable iff the determinant is nonzero.

Based on the definition of matrix multiplication, we know that the simultaneous equations given are equivalent to $$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}e\\f\end{bmatrix}$$
Call the matrix $A$.  Multiply on both sides by the inverse of the matrix. Applying $A^{-1}A=I$, $I$ being the identity matrix, we get that $[x\,y]=A^{-1}[e\, f]$, so it follows that the existence of the inverse implies that the equations are solvable.

To get the implication in the other direction (equations solvable implies inverse exists), let $x_1, y_1$ be the solution of the simultaneous equations for $e=1, f=0$, and let $x_2, y_2$ be the solution for $e=0, f=1$.  We have
$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2\\y_1&y_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}ax_1+by_1&ax_2+by_2\\cx_1+dy_1&cx_2+dy_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
The latter matrix is the identity, so the inverse exists and equals
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2\\y_1&y_2\end{bmatrix}.$$